# Package biblatex Warning: 'babel/polyglossia' detected but 'csquotes' missing

Tags: warnings

I can compile my `.tex` file without problem but I'm getting a warning that I don't understand. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % Manejo de idiomas
\usepackage[pages = some]{background} 
\usepackage[style=ieee, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Anteproyecto.bib}

%\usepackage{nomencl}
%\makenomenclature
%%\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}

\backgroundsetup{
contents={\includegraphics{escudounipamplona.png}},
angle=0, 
scale=0.45, 
color=black, 
opacity=0.1
}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{M{#1}}

\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,top=4cm,headheight=75pt,footskip=65pt]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.95cm}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancyhead[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all headers
\fancyhead[C]{%
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|M{3.0cm}|X|M{2.5cm}|M{3cm}|}
    \hline
    \multirow{4}*{\includegraphics[scale=0.034]{escudounipamplona}}
    &
    \multirow{4}*{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering Propuesta trabajo de grado para optar por el título de Ingeniero en Mecatrónica}}
    &
    \multirow{2}*{\textbf{C\'odigo}}
    &
    \multirow{2}*{1.2}\\
    &&&
    \\\cline{3-4}
    &&
    \multirow{2}*{\textbf{Pagina}}
    &
    \multirow{2}*{\small\emph{Pagina \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}}\hspace{15pt}}\\
    &&&\\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
}

\begin{document}
\BgThispage
\begin{center}
{
\Large\textbf{Detecci\'on y diagnostico de fallas basados en t\'ecnicas de aprendizaje autom\'atico supervisado: aplicaci\'on al problema del benchmark DAMADICS}  
\vspace{3cm}
\\
{\normalsize \textit{Autor}} \\
Juan David Bola\~nos Aguilar\\

\vspace{3cm}

{\normalsize \textit{Director}} \\
Dr. Rocco Tarantino Alvarado \\
{\normalsize \textit{Doctorado en Ciencias Aplicadas}} \\
\vspace{3cm}
Programa de ingenier\'ia mecatr\'onica \\
Departamento de ingenier\'ia mec\'anica, mecatr\'onica e industrial \\
Facultad de ingenierías y arquitectura\\
Universidad de Pamplona\\
Villa del Rosario, Norte de Santander\\
febrero del 2015\\
}
\end{center}
\newpage
\BgThispage
\begin{center}
{

\Large\textbf{Detecci\'on y diagnostico de fallas basados en t\'ecnicas de aprendizaje autom\'atico supervisado: aplicaci\'on al problema del benchmark DAMADICS}  
\vspace{2.5cm}
\\
{\normalsize \textit{Autor}} \\
Juan David Bola\~nos Aguilar \\
{\normalsize \textit{Codigo: 1116249797}} \\
{\normalsize \textit{Correo electronico: judabo@unipamplona.edu.co}} \\
\vspace{2.5cm}
{\normalsize \textit{Director}} \\
Dr. Rocco Tarantino Alvarado \\
{\normalsize \textit{Doctorado en Ciencias Aplicadas}} 
\\
{\normalsize \textit{Correo electronico: rocco.tarantino@unipamplona.edu.co}} \\
\vspace{2.5cm}
Programa de ingenier\'ia mecatr\'onica \\
Departamento de ingenier\'ia mec\'anica, mecatr\'onica e industrial \\
Facultad de ingenierías y arquitectura\\
Universidad de Pamplona\\
Villa del Rosario, Norte de Santander\\
febrero del 2015\\
}
\end{center}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{INTRODUCCI\'ON}
La supervisión de procesos técnicos tiene como objetivo ilustrar el estado actual del proceso, indicar estados no deseados o no permitidos y tomar acciones encaminadas a la corrección de los mismos con el fin de evitar da\~nos o accidentes \cite{isermannFault}. Esta disciplina permite el desarrollo de metodos sistematicos que permiten la deteccion y posterior de \textbf{fallas} en plantas industriales que derivan en perdidas económicas, paro de produccion, daños en actuadores y sensores, entre otros. De manera precisa, se define una falla como 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And this is a fragment with the warning:

```
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'spanish'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'spanish.lbx' found.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/spanish.lbx
File: spanish.lbx 2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
)
Package biblatex Warning: 'babel/polyglossia' detected but 'csquotes' missing.
(biblatex) Loading 'csquotes' recommended.
\@quotelevel=\count289
\@quotereset=\count290
(build/Anteproyecto.aux
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sptext on input line 28.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \. on input line 28.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \% on input line 28.
)
```

SO: Ubuntu 14.04 - Texmaker

Answer (score 126, accepted):

When using `babel` or `polyglossia` with `biblatex`, loading `csquotes` is recommended to ensure that quoted texts are typeset according to the rules of your main language.

So add

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
```

to your document preamble.

Comment: before or after `babel`, `polyglossia` or `biblatex`?

Comment: Tested now and found that you can add `csquotes` after all of them.